# TinyMCE CakePHP 3.0+ not selecting textarea (nothing happens)

Tags: tinymce, cakephp-3.0

CakePHP seems to be loading the plugin because I'm not getting any errors when loading from bootstrap, including the helper in the control and then using it in the view, but nothing happens to my `<textarea></textarea>` tags which I placed before and after the script in the view. I have also loaded jQuery. Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Controller:
    `public $helpers = ['TinyMCE.TinyMCE'];`

View:
     `<textarea></textarea>
    $this->TinyMCE->editor(array('theme' => 'advanced'));
    <textarea></textarea>`

HTML (view source, when the page is loaded):

```
<textarea>
</textarea>

<script>
//<![CDATA[
tinymce.init({
script : "/TinyMCE/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js",
load_script : "1",
theme : "advanced"
});
//]]>
</script>

<textarea>
</textarea>
```

Bootstrap:
    `Plugin::load('TinyMCE', ['autoload' => true]);`

```
Configure::write('TinyMCE.configs', array(
'advanced' => array(
'mode' => 'textareas',
'theme' => 'advanced')));
```

I also just noticed, when I `pr($this->TinyMCE);`

I get:

```
TinyMCE\View\Helper\TinyMCEHelper Object
(
[helpers] => Array
    (
        [0] => Html
    )

[theme] => 
[plugin] => 
[fieldset] => Array
    (
    )

[tags] => Array
    (
    )

[implementedEvents] => Array
    (
        [View.beforeRender] => beforeRender
    )

[_config] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

For some reason there is nothing in [theme] value, it should be - advanced. What am I doing wrong? Is something wrong with this line:

```
$this->TinyMCE->editor(array('theme' => 'advanced'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Helper TinyMCE for CakePHP 2 with preset function.

TinyMCE

Download TinyMCE : http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php
Copy /tinymce/jscripts/ tiny_mce folder to /app/webroot/js (like : /app/webroot/js/tiny_mce).
Controller

```
public $helpers = array('Tinymce');
```

Behavior

```
$this->Tinymce->input($Model.fieldName, $options = array(), $tinyoptions = array(), $preset = null)
```

Example

```
    <div class="posts form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post');?>
    <fieldset>
            <legend><?php echo __('Add Post'); ?></legend>
    <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('title');
            echo $this->Tinymce->input('Post.content', array(
                    'label' => 'Content'
                    ),array(
                            'language'=>'en'
                    ),
                    'bbcode'
        );
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
</div>
```

http://bakery.cakephp.org/2012/04/11/Helper-TinyMCE-for-CakePHP-2.html#

Comment: Okay.....but I'm not interested in TinyMCE for CakePHP 2, my question is about CakePHP 3.0+